# Azure stream analytics UTC time stamp

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

how to get the UTC time stamp in ASA ? system.timestamp provides the UTC time stamp

Comment: Not sure what you're asking since you answered your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CSharpRocks said, it seems that you had known how to get the UTC timestamp in ASA. According to the offical reference [`Time Management (Azure Stream Analytics)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt582045), here is just a proof for UTC timestamp in ASA, as below.

> All time handling operations in Azure Stream Analytics are in UTC.

And from the reference [System.Timestamp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt598501).

> Every event at every stage of the query in Azure Stream Analytics has a timestamp associated with it. **System.Timestamp** is a system property that can be used to retrieve the event’s timestamp.